# Delete files from directory if filename contains a certain word

Tags: c#, file-io, directory, exists

I need to check a directory to see if there are any files whose file name contains a specific keyword and if there are, to delete them.  Is this possible?

For example, delete all existing files in "`C:\Folder`" whose file name contains the keyword "Apple".

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To expand on Henk's answer, you need:

```
string rootFolderPath = @"C:\\SomeFolder\\AnotherFolder\\FolderCOntainingThingsToDelete";
string filesToDelete = @"*DeleteMe*.doc";   // Only delete DOC files containing "DeleteMe" in their filenames
string[] fileList = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(rootFolderPath, filesToDelete);
foreach(string file in fileList)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(file + "will be deleted");
//  System.IO.File.Delete(file);
}
```

**BE VERY CAREFUL!**

Note that I've commented out the delete command. Run it and test it *carefully* before you let it actually delete anything!

If you wish to recursively delete files in ALL subfolders of the root folder, add ,System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories); to the GetFiles call.

If you do this it is also a **very** good idea to refuse to run if the rootFolderPath is less than about 4 characters long (a simple protection against deleting everything in C:\  - I've been there and done that and it's not fun!!!)

Comment: And don't forget to catch exceptions, to handle situations where the file is in use, or access is denied, etc.

Comment: Thank you.  Added the catch exceptions as well.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()` to a list of the files, in string[] format.

<strike>Then you can use `System.IO.File.ReadAllText()` to read complete files, or if they are very big, open a TextReader with `System.IO.File.OpenText()`.</strike>

If you are looking for a literal keyword, `String.Contains()` is all you need.

Deleting a file can be done with `System.IO.File.Delete()`. Make sure the file is closed again.

Edit, 2 examples of `GetFiles()`:

```
string[] fileNames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\");
string[] fileNames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", @"*.sys");
```

Comment: Whoops, guess I should have worded it a bit different.  I don't need to check within the file itself, but rather just the file name.

Comment: Then you can skip the ReadAllText/TextReader steps.

Comment: There is no need to read all text. E.g. if File starts with Apple and it is 50mb... The better way is to read files sequentially with slide window.

Comment: Trickster, see the TextReader part.

Comment: @Nate: the `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles` method that Henk suggests in his answer gives you the filenames as a string array.

Answer (score 8):

```
new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Folder")).ForEach(file => {
    if (file.IndexOf("apple", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        File.Delete(file);
});
```

or

```
new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Folder")).ForEach(file => {
    Regex re = new Regex("apple", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (re.IsMatch(file))
        File.Delete(file);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

More or less, this:

```
string DeleteThis = "apple";
string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Folder");

foreach (string file in Files)
{
    if (file.ToUpper().Contains(DeleteThis.ToUpper()))
    {
        File.Delete(file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Folder")).ForEach(file => { if (file.ToUpper().Contains("apple".ToUpper())) File.Delete(file); });
```