# Transfer files in using c#

Tags: c#, file, copy

how can I copy files from folder to another when by using c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.IO.File.Copy
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a good example from MSDN:

[How to: Copy, Delete, and Move Files and Folders (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx)

Comment: +1 For the best way for the asker to learn - Also, welcome to SO:)

Answer (score 2):

The System.IO.File, System.IO.Directory, System.IO.FileInfo classes "Mr.Expert" suggested above are fine for copying and deleting individual files.

But if you are deleting/copying large number of files you are probably better off using an alternative method see this question I asked previous..

[Delete a large number (>100K) of files with c# whilst maintaining performance in a web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185837/delete-a-large-number-100k-of-files-with-c-whilst-maintaining-performance-in)

The System.IO.Directory.GetFiles can cause a performance issue when dealing with large number of files.