# C# delete files in folder with filter

Tags: c#, filter, delete-file

I am using SharpDevelop to write a C# program (not console).
I want to delete files within a specified directory, but be able to EXCLUDE files beginning, ending, or containing certain words.

TO completely delete ALL files in a folder I am using this :

```
private void clearFolder(string FolderName)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(FolderName);

    foreach(FileInfo fi in dir.GetFiles())
    {
        fi.Delete();
    }

    foreach (DirectoryInfo di in dir.GetDirectories())
    {
        clearFolder(di.FullName);
        di.Delete();
    }
}
```

I use it like

```
ClearFolder("NameOfFolderIWantToEmpty");
```

Is there a way to modify this so that I can delete all files and direcotries EXCEPT those files and directories containing specific words?

Something like :

```
CleanFolder(FolderToEmpty,ExcludeAllFileAndDirectoriesContaingThisPhrase);
```

so that if I did

```
CleanFolder("MyTestFolder","_blink");
```

It would NOT delete files and directories with names like

```
_blinkOne (file)

Test_blineGreen (file)

Test_blink5 (directory)

_blinkTwo (file within the Text_blink5 directory)

Folder_blink (empty directory)
```

but WOULD delete files and directories like

```
test (file)

test2 (directory)

test3_file (file within test2 directory)

test4 (empty directory)
```

I suspect I might have to iterate through each file and directory, checking them one at a time for the matching filter and deleting it if it does not match, but I am not sure how to do that.

Something with `FileInfo()` and `DirectoryInfo()` perhaps?

Can somebody help by providing a working example?
(modified version of the above is preferred, but if a new method is required, as long as it doesn't require an outside dll, is OK.

Comment: All the answers are correct, if any one of them helped you so choose it as answer so no one will waste time to read your question again , because it has already been answered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Delete files from directory if filename contains a certain word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620366/c-sharp-delete-files-from-directory-if-filename-contains-a-certain-word)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a solution that will work for me.
Posting the full code here so that others may use it, tweak it, and/or examine it for possible flaws.
This is my first time using StackOverFlow, and knowing that I have this resource available to search and the ability to ask questions and people can actually help, is a great comfort to me as a person who is new to all of this stuff.

Thanks a ton everybody!

// Search directory recursively and delete ALL sub-directories and files

// with names that do NOT contain the given search pattern

```
private void clearFolderWithFilter(string folderName, string filesToExclude)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderName);

    foreach(FileInfo fi in dir.GetFiles())
    {
        if(!fi.Name.Contains(filesToExclude))
        {
            // System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DELETING file " + fi + " because it does NOT contain '" + filesToExclude + "' ");
            fi.Delete();
        } else {
            // System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SAVING file " + fi + " because it contains '" + filesToExclude + "' ");
        }
    }

    foreach (DirectoryInfo di in dir.GetDirectories())
    {
        if(!di.Name.Contains(filesToExclude))
        {
            // System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DELETING directory " + di + " because it does NOT contain '" + filesToExclude + "' ");
            clearFolderWithFilter(di.FullName, filesToExclude);
            di.Delete();
        } else {
            // System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SAVING directory " + di + " because it contains '" + filesToExclude + "' ");
        }
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
clearFolderWithFilter(@"C:\Path\MyFolder","DoNotDelete_");
```

Comment: This code will throw an exception as it will try to delete folder that contain folders named "DoNotDelete_". Those were not deleted so their ancestor folders won't be empty and di.Delete() will fail. I would suggest tweaking this by returning an indication for whether a file or folder was skipped so that there will not be an attempt to delete a folder if something was skipped inside it. This should be OR-ed with the results of previous return values so that we won't try to delete c:\Path\MyFolder if it contains the path c:\Path\MyFolder\A\B\C\D\DoNotDelete_.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`Directory.GetFiles(string, string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) method to get a list of files that *match* your pattern, and use `Enumerable.Except(IEnumerable<T>)` to get the files you actually want to delete.

```
string pattern = "*.*";
var matches = Directory.GetFiles(folderName, pattern);
foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles(folderName).Except(matches))
    File.Delete(file);
```

There's no need to use DirectoryInfo here, since you appear to be concerned only with manipulating the files in the directory.

Comment: I am wanting to delete all directories and files and sub-directories (and all the files-n- directories within)..etc. that do NOT match the search pattern. Will give this a shot and see what happens. will post results when resolved. THANKS!

Comment: @CopalFreak: I understand that. the best way to do that is to get a list of files that *do* match, and delete all files that aren't in the match list.

Comment: Where you have "Except(matches))"..I get one of those lovely "System.Array does not contain a definition for 'Except'.." errors.. Am I missing a "using System.Something;" at the top? I have System and System.IO .. not sure where the Except (or Contains ) might be.. Google searches dont seem to be helping much, I suspect because 'Except' may not be part of the standard c# stuff...not sure on that tho..am still a noob. hehe . Any suggestions? Thanks!!

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but I do not want to use .NET stuff, because, as I currently understand it, it would result in having to include an extra .dll file and/or making the program larger. For my needs, I want to keep it a single portable exe file.

Comment: @CopalFreak: Except is a LINQ method. You need `using System.Linq` and a reference to `System.Core.dll`. Otherwise, you could replace the except method with `if(matches.Contains(file)) continue;` in the loop body.

Comment: I was able to modify a combination of this and another answer to get it working. (wish I could 'VoteUp' but still new here).Thanks!

Comment: please add the quotation marks arround your pattern string:  - string pattern = "*.*";

Answer (score 3):

Just test to see if the `FileInfo.Name` property (string) `StartsWith` or `EndsWith` a specified string.

```
    foreach (FileInfo fInfo in di.GetFiles())
    {
        if (!fInfo.Name.StartsWith("AAA") || 
            !fInfo.Name.EndsWith("BBB"))
        {
            fInfo.Delete();
        }
    }
```

Or if you are looking for a word anywhere in the filename, use the `Contains` method:

```
    foreach (FileInfo fInfo in di.GetFiles())
    {
        if (!fInfo.Name.Contains("CCC")) 
        {
            fInfo.Delete();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This method seems to check the files in the main directory only, and none  of the subdirectories(their names) or files within those subdirectories. I think it might be a good method for me to use, but I am just missing some part of it that would make it do that. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to modify a combination of this and another answer to get it working. (wish I could 'VoteUp' but still new here).Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!fi.Name.Contains("_blink"))
      fi.Delete();
```

Comment: I think I tried using this method before and it had some problem with the 'Contains' part. Will try anyway and will post results when I have em. THANKS!

Comment: Getting an error that says there is no definition for 'Contains' and no extension method 'Contains'. As with the other answer here, I suspect I am missing a "using System.Something" up at the top, but no clue what that would be. Would like to try out both of these methods though. Thanks!

Comment: after adding "using System.Linq" per Jason Watkins suggestion, I found that, the way I currently tested this method, would only check the main directory itself and none of the files or subfolders within. Thanks though.

Comment: I was able to modify a combination of this and another answer to get it working. (wish I could 'VoteUp' but still new here).Thanks!